# How to know in a END block whether the program died?

Tags: raku

Is it possible to know within an END block, if the program died? In Perl I would do this

```
END {
    if ( $? == 255 ) {
        # ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Good question!

There's none that I know of.  That is why I created a [Pull Request](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/pull/4988) to make the following possible:

```
END {
    unless $*DIED-NATURALLY {
        # do special cleanup actions
    }
}
```